# Access User Control Variable from Form

Tags: vb.net, forms, variables, user-controls

I have a *Listview* control in a **User Control** and I want to access the selected item(s) from **Form1**. Even if I declare it as a public variable I cannot access it from any other forms.

The following code line would be in Form1:

```
   Dim Index As Integer = UserControl1.Listview1.SelectedItems(0).Index
```

The issue is I cannot even get the "Listview1" intellisense to pop up. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new module and declare a variable as public for your usercontrol
and type this into

```
public myLV as UserControl1.Listview1
```

So you can change your code with

```
Dim Index As Integer = myLV.SelectedItems(0).Index
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by default in VB.Net, but you've mentioned other forms in the description.  Which form is the UserControl on?...and which form are you trying to access that UserControl from?

If attempting to access across forms, then how are you getting a reference to the other form?  I suspect you simply have a wrong reference and are accessing an empty ListView from an invisible form (created but not displayed).

Show us some code where you're attempting this...

Comment: What do you mean which form is the UserControl on ... I created it by creating a new item > UserControl ... There is no control "UserControl" to add into my main form. The code I would of paste is "UserControl1.Listview1" ... Yet no Listview1 pops up in the intellisence.

Comment: You need an INSTANCE of your Usercontrol, so either add one to your Form (re-build first and it will be at the top of your ToolBox), or create one in code: `Dim uc1 As New UserControl1 ... uc1.ListView1.Items` You'll be able to see the ListView in the reference to an actual instance of your UserControl.

Comment: If your UserControl is called "UserControl1" and you added one to your form, then the default name would be "UserControl11" (note there two ones at the end; the IDE adds a number after the name).  So your code snippet would need to be: `Dim Index As Integer = UserControl11.Listview1.SelectedItems(0).Index`

Comment: I'm trying to access my UserControl1 controls (Listview, textboxes, labels etc) from my MainForm.vb. So I'm trying to write the same code you wrote to access my selected items in my UserControl1 listview...

Comment: I understand that.  Have you dragged the custom UserControl from the ToolBox to your form?...or are you creating it in code?  The UserControl by itself is like a cookie cutter.  It doesn't have anything in it until you press it into the dough.  Adding the UserControl to the form, or creating it via code with the "New" keyword is what makes it a tangible "cookie" that you can work with.

Comment: It really didn't appear in my ToolBox. I cleaned, rebuilt my code and nothing ... Although, I did add it as a new item, and built the interface like a normal form. Then I just add it to a panel on my form. I was able to access the variables by passing them through modules.

Comment: There's something not quite right with your project/setup then.  That's not the way it's supposed to work.